# How to calculate the following limit $ \lim_{n\to +\infty} {\frac n{\ln(n)}}(\sqrt[n]n-1) $

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} {\frac n{\ln(n)}}(\sqrt[n]n-1) $$ I know I can simply subtitute x=ln(n)/n but if I don't find the right substitution at the moment (its part of an exam I'll take) how can I solve it in another way?

Comment: There is no $x$ in the expression.  Do you mean the limit as $n\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Why $x\to 0$?Typo? Maybe you mean $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Also, is this part of an active exam?

Comment: You know that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x}{\ln{x}} = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{1/x} = 0$.

Comment: yes sorry edited it,its n to infinity

Answer (score 6):

$$\sqrt[n]{n} = \exp\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right) = 1+\frac{\log n}{n}+O\left(\frac{\log^2 n}{n^2}\right) $$
hence the given limit equals $\color{red}{\large 1}$.